# mongodb cursor map function in java

Tags: mongodb

i have a collection 'placements', each document has fields: placement_id, program_id, category, ... i need to find all placements what has program_id = 3 and only return a list of placement_id, 
i can do it from mongo command line like this:

```
db.placements.find({program_id:{$in: [3]}}, {placement_id:1, _id:0}).map( function(doc){return doc.placement_id})
```

it return placement_ids in a array:

```
[196, 197, 198...]
```

but how can i implement the above query in Java, i checked the mongodb java api's DBCursor class, it doesn't have any function as 'map' or 'forEach'.

Comment: If it is only about fetching the placement id, you can loop through the cursor output of the query- db.placements.find({program_id:{$in: [3]}}, {placement_id:1, _id:0})

Comment: that query return { "placement_id" : 196 } { "placement_id" : 197 }{ "placement_id" : 198 }..., that's not what i want

Answer (score 0):

The `DBCursor.next` returns `DBOBject` which has a `get` method which you can use to push the values to an array.
I am thinking of something like this. (Not tested)

```
List<Integer> placementIdList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
while (cursor.hasNext()) {
  DBObject obj = cursor.next();
  int id = obj.get("placement_id");
  placementIdList.add(id);
}
```

UPDATE :
The implementation on the database side for the `map` implementation is very similar to above.

```
mongos> db.test.find().map
function ( func ){
    var a = [];
    while ( this.hasNext() )
        a.push( func( this.next() ) );
    return a;
}
```

So either you do it in db or in the Java layer.
Advantage of doing it in db would be transmitting a slimmer packet across the wire (lesser serialization/deserialization costs), whereas doing it in Java you can take advantage of the processing power of a JVM.

Comment: sure it works, just wonder if there some mongo builtin function to allow me to do it more efficiently. when there are millions of documents in the collection, this loop can be very slow.

Comment: I understand your concern. added an update which might address some of it.